# Cannot get li that belong to a specific ul

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-group-item px-0">
        <h2>Foo</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <h3>Test</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="list-group-item px-0">
        <h2>Contoso</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <h3>Test 2</h3>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to grab all the `li` which belongs to the node in iteration, which is the first `ul`, so the result should return: Foo and Contoso but I get all the li available, this is my code:

```
var liCollection = node.SelectNodes(".//ul/li[@class='list-group-item']");
```

I can fix this adding `px-0` but is possible to get only the li associated to the first `ul` in iteration?

Full code:

https://pastebin.com/wjE2q1n2

Comment: @Stefan Sorry was just my example (fixed) to show the full code: https://pastebin.com/wjE2q1n2

Comment: I think your problem is "//ul" instead of "/ul". With two // your are searching in all ul elements. With one, only in the current element. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @Victor if I switch to `node.SelectNodes("./ul/li");` I get `null`. If you look at the full code, you can see that `node` is actually the accordion, eg: `<div id="collapse0"`

Comment: Try getting only the first node (SelectSingleNode). You get the first li. Then, get closest ul (or the parent, which it's the same) and use the XPath single / to get the li ("./li[@class='list-group-item']" if I'm not wrong)

Comment: when you just need `Food` and `Contosso`, you can also do `//ul/li/h2`   (Or, with this example data: `//h2`)

Comment: @Luuk I need the li tag, and if I do `//ul/li` I will get the child associated to the nested `ul`

Comment: OK, when you need the `li` tag, you still can do: `//ul/li/h2/..`, which will select the parent of `h2`

Comment: Or do `//li[count(ancestor::*)=1]`   and change the `1` to the appropriate number.

Comment: @Luuk Could you show me a working example based on the full html source I added to the question please?

Comment: @sfarzoso you need `A01A, A02A, A02B, A03A, ...` from the html source?

Comment: @ggeorge need three list actually: `A, B, C, D, G ...`, then for each element (eg A): `A01, A02, A03`, then for each of this (eg A03): `A03A, A03B, A03F`

Comment: @sfarzoso Take a look at the updated answer. I shared an approach that all data is combined and extracted as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a complete different selection:

```
html1 = File.ReadAllText("input.html");
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html1);

var i = 0;
var uls = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class]/../../div[1]/*");
foreach (HtmlNode ul in uls)
{
    var group = ul.InnerText.Replace('\r',' ').Replace('\n',' ').Trim();
    foreach( HtmlNode subul in ul.SelectNodes("./../../div[2]/*"))
    {
        var sub = subul.InnerText.Trim();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sub)) Console.WriteLine($"{group}: {sub}");
    }
}
```

output:

```
A: Apparato gastrointestinale e metabolismo
A01: Preparati stomatologici
A01A: Preparazioni stomatologiche
A02: Farmaci per malattie correlate all'acidosi
A02A: Antiacidi
A02B: Farmaci per l'ulcera peptica e la malattia da reflusso gastroesofageo (gerd)
A03: Farmaci per malattie gastrointestinali funzionali
A03A: Farmaci malattie gastrointestinali funzionali
A03B: Belladonna e derivati
A03F: Procinetici
A04: Antiemetici e antinausea
A04A: Antiemetici e antinausea
A05: Bile e terapia del fegato
A05A: Terapia per la bile
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample for your needs. I think this is what you want to achieve!

```
var list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    "//div[@class='shadow-sm autoscroll my-1']"); 

var collection = list.Select(x => x.SelectNodes(".//ul/li[@class='list-group-item']"));

//This is for "A", "B" etc
var category = list.Select(x => x.SelectNodes(".//span[contains(@class, 'badge-light')]"));

//This is for "A01A" etc
var listTitles = list.Select(x => x.SelectNodes(".//ul/li[@class='list-group-item']//span"));

//This is for "Preparazioni stomatologiche" etc
var descriptions = list.Select(x => x.SelectNodes(".//ul/li[@class='list-group-item']//a"));
```

With this as guide you can scrape the data you really desire..

**UPDATE**

Combined together:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/html.txt");

var data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='shadow-sm autoscroll my-1']");

List<dynamic> objects = new();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    foreach (var sub in item.SelectNodes(".//ul[contains(@class, 'list-group')]//li"))
    {
        var obj = new
        {
            Category = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='mb-1']//span").InnerText.Trim(),
            Description = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='mb-1']//h2").InnerText.Trim(),
            Sub = new
            {
                SubCategories = sub.SelectSingleNode(".//span").InnerText.Trim(),
                SubDescriptions = sub.SelectSingleNode(".//a").InnerText.Trim(),
            }            
        };
        objects.Add(obj); 
    }
}

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(objects, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCkUa.png